# Backup BizTalk Server (BizTalkMgmtDb)

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

Below is the configuration I have for Backup BizTalk Server (BizTalkMgmtDb) job

```
Set Compression Option :exec [dbo].[sp_SetBackupCompression] @bCompression = 1
BackupFull : exec [dbo].[sp_BackupAllFull_Schedule] 'd' ,'BTS','D:\BTS_SQL_Backup','0','15'
MarkAndBackUpLog : exec [dbo].[sp_MarkAll] 'BTS' , 'D:\BTS_MarkAndBackupLog'
Clear Backup History : exec [dbo].[sp_DeleteBackupHistory] @DaysToKeep=14, @UseLocalTime =1
```

Below is the error I got

> Error: cannot Open backup device 'D:\BTS_MarkAndBackupLog'

Please advise.

User has admin rights , attached screenshot for reference .

[image]

Comment: As this is not a programming question, but rather a server configuration question it is of topic for Stackoverflow.  It would be on topic on https://serverfault.com but as there are very few BizTalk experts, and they don't visit there often, you probably have more chance of getting help on the thread you started on Technet https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8dd8afb7-b062-40f3-bac7-e53c5eb0b8f3/backup-biztalk-server-biztalkmgmtdb?forum=biztalkgeneral

Comment: Okay , Sure Dijkgraaf .

Comment: Does the "D:\BTS_MarkAndBackupLog" folder exists?

Answer (score 0):

From the Technet thread

> I was able to fix the issue by providing network path instead of actual local drive location . ( Folder Properties --> Sharing --> Add user to the network -- > Network Path ).